# Grades of each quiz in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to get grades of each question, I have a query but it only return final grade of whole exam, but i want grade of each question, how to get it?
Here is query that i have:

```
SELECT mdl_grade_items.id AS ItemID,
   mdl_course.shortname AS CourseShortname,
   mdl_grade_items.itemname AS ItemName,
   mdl_grade_items.grademax AS ItemGradeMax,
   mdl_grade_items.aggregationcoef AS ItemAggregation,
   mdl_grade_grades.finalgrade AS FinalGrade,
   mdl_user.username AS StudentID,
   mdl_user.id
FROM mdl_grade_items
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades 
ON mdl_grade_items.id = mdl_grade_grades.itemid
INNER JOIN mdl_role_assignments 
ON mdl_grade_grades.userid = mdl_role_assignments.userid 
AND mdl_grade_items.courseid = mdl_role_assignments.mdlcourseid
INNER JOIN mdl_course 
ON mdl_course.id = mdl_grade_items.courseid
INNER JOIN mdl_user 
ON mdl_user.id = mdl_role_assignments.userid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found it

```
SELECT mqa.id,meqi.grade * (select fraction from mdl_question_attempt_steps where  
questionattemptid = mqas.questionattemptid and state like 'mangr%' order by id desc limit 
1 ) finalgrade,me.course , mqas.userid,u.firstname, u.lastname, mqa.questionsummary,  
mqa.responsesummary , meqi.grade
FROM mdl_question_attempts mqa
left JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps mqas ON mqa.id = mqas.questionattemptid
left JOIN mdl_user u ON mqas.userid = u.id
left JOIN mdl_examm_question_instances meqi ON meqi.question = mqa.questionid
left JOIN mdl_examm me ON meqi.examm = me.id
WHERE  me.course= $courseID and userid = $userID
```